# How to fix this pyramid pattern in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this output:
[image]

This is my code, what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int number;
bool flag;

    do {
        cout << "\t\t\Menu\n";
        cout << "Enter a number between 6 and 12.\n";
        cin >> number;

        if (number > 5 && number < 13) {
            flag = true;
            for(int index = 1; index <= number; ++index) {

                //Loop for spaces.
                for(int spaces = index; spaces < number; ++spaces) {
                    cout << " ";
                }

                //Loop for numbers.
                int counter = index;
                int counter2 = 1;
                for(int index2 = 1; index2 <= (2 * index - 1); ++index2) {
                    if (counter > 0) cout << counter--;
                    else cout << ++counter2;
                }

                cout << "\n";
            }

        } else cout << "Enter a valid number!\n";

    } while (!flag);

return 0;
}
```

My output:

[image]

How to fix my output with proper spaces, I tried to concatenate with spaces but it doesn't fit good, how to fit it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to output a few more spaces here:

```
for(int spaces = index; spaces < number; ++spaces) {
    cout << "     ";
}
```

To handle different number length well, I suggest C++'s equivalent of `printf()` and format string, `cout << setw()`:

```
#include <iomanip>

cout << setw(4) << number;
```

... or just use `printf`:

```
printf("%4d", number);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this answer didn't work, I tried it but I got weird outputs, by the way `number` is not intended to be printed, I print the spaces " ", `counter` and `counter2` only.

Comment: @Rafa Try adjusting the number of spaces and the value in `setw`.

Comment: Indeed you're right, I was having issues with the Code::Blocks IDE output window size which was not maximized so the IDE kinda squeezed them out to the corner. Using the `setw(4)` for `counter` and `counter2` solved the problem! Thank you very much! By the way I'm not happy with my IDE, do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: Actually it's not the Code::Blocks IDE output window size, I found out it's the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS XTerm output window size instead. Anyway I still find that IDE is not suitable for me, I expected something more like IntelliJ IDEA since I'm getting used to it.